# XForms: decoding Base64 Encoded string

Tags: xml, xpath, orbeon, xforms

Part of my form involves retrieval of some of the values from a web service. The web service provides this in the form of a Base64 encoded string, which I need to decode and insert into my main instance. I am using the following to try to achieve this:

```
<xf:insert
    context="instance('fr-form-instance')"
    ref="instance('fr-form-instance')" 
    origin="
        saxon:parse(
            saxon:base64Binary-to-string(
                xs:base64Binary(
                    instance('fr-service-response-instance')//*:Base64String
                ), 
                'UTF-8'
            )
        )"
/>
```

But this is not working and no exception is thrown in the log file. I have alerts set up before and after this line so I know the line is being hit as expected, but the second alert (just after the line) doesn't get hit, so something is going wrong.

Comment: You have mapped the `saxon` prefix somewhere, right?

Comment: Question closed. The Base64String was being encoded using Unicode, not UTF-8, thank you DBAs, it would be nice if you informed the developers of this change!

Comment: Glad it's working now.